# Can Premature end of script headers be properly debugged? (getting the real error message?)

Tags: php, apache-2.4, debugging

We are getting

```
[Wed Aug 25 15:06:05.484053 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 24792:tid 140550620227328] [client xxxx:40224] Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer: https://www.example.com/
[Wed Aug 25 15:06:05.484091 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 24792:tid 140550620227328] [client xxxx:40224] AH01070: Error parsing script headers, referer: https://www.example.com/
[Wed Aug 25 15:06:05.484111 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 24792:tid 140550620227328] (22)Invalid argument: [client xxxx:40224] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : , referer: https://www.example.com/
```

in a Apache + PHP7.4-FCGI setup.

While we already think to know the cause of this (too huge header's sent by Magento) and there are tons of other questions about this, we did not find information on how to get to a proper error message.

Is there some logging which can be increased between FCGI and Apache?

Neither the php7.4-fpm log nor the apache log does seem to reveal the root cause of this problem.